Modify parent component output based on boolean value set in child component in Angular
I'm new to Angular and need help on how to best deal with a situation using Angular 16.
Basically I have two components for two different versions of our site header, one is the default and the other is for certain pages. The component for the header is being called in app.component.html but I'd like to add a conditional here so that when certain pages are being viewed (each page being a component) it displays the alternative header.
I figured the way to do this was to have a boolean that is false by default, but in the components where we want the alternative header we'd change the boolean to true... but I can't identify the best way to do this. I've seen a lot tutorials regarding sending data from a child component to a parent component, but most seem to assume the value being sent is generated by the user and not automatically by a component simply being used or require importing the child component into the parent.
What's the best way to do this and if there's a known tutorial that would help me that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You header component is set in the app.component.html which means the best way to handle the custom flag is from app.component.ts.
Set the value of the flag in each of route state and read that value in app.component.ts by subscribing to navigationEnd. You can then pass this value to the header component.

As you say, the "header" change according the router. So, I understand you need check when the router change. where? in the component where the "header" is
  headerValue!:any
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.router.events.pipe(
          filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd))
           .subscribe((res:any)=>{
             switch (res.url)
           {
             case "/":
             case "/first-component":
               this.headerValue=false;
               break;
             ...
             default:
               this.headerValue=true;
           }
         })
  }

You have in main:
  @if (headerValue)
  {
    <app-header-1></app-header-1>
  }
  @else{
    <app-header-2></app-header-2>
  }

NOTE: this tecnica is the same that when we have an unique header, but we want pass a variable to the header when change.
The unique app-header:
  @Input() headerValue:boolean=false

  //template
  @if (headerValue)
  {
    header value is true
  }
  @else{
    header value is false
  }

